# Format a String to Pascal Case

Tags: swift

Using **Swift 4**, how to format a String with those rules:

- Capitalize first letter if the word is longer than 3 letters,
  otherwise Uppercased
- Pascal case words that contains an hyphen like St-Michel

I have a first draft here, but I'm stuck with how to tackle the second point. Also, currently I add a white space at the end when it shouldn't.

```
var pascalCase: String {
    return self.components(separatedBy: " ")
        .map {
            if $0.count > 3 {
                return $0.uppercased()
            } else {
                return $0.lowercased().capitalizingFirstLetter()
            }
        }
        .map { return $0 + " " }
        .joined()
}
```

Comment: What about `(separedBy: "-").map{ $0.lowercased().capitalizingFirstLetter() }.joined("-")}`?

Comment: @Larme Oooh I didn't know you could have a separator in .joined() . NICE! :D (If you format a good answer i'll accept it)

Comment: It's annoying the built-in `.capitalized` lowercases all remaining letters in each word without leaving them alone as one would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I have your requirements correct, this works:

```
extension String {
    var pascalCase: String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: " ")
            .map {
                if $0.count <= 3 {
                    return $0.uppercased()
                } else {
                    if $0.index(of: "-") != nil {
                        return $0.components(separatedBy: "-").map { $0.pascalCase }.joined(separator: "-")
                    } else {
                        return $0.capitalized
                    }
                }
            }
            .joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

print("hello".pascalCase)
print("hi".pascalCase)
print("this is fun".pascalCase)
print("st-michael".pascalCase)
```

Results:

> Hello
>   HI
>   This IS FUN
>   ST-Michael

Comment: If this is not the desired output then please update your question with some clear examples of input and desired output.